# Lapack to solve A*X=B'

Tags: lapack, lapacke

I would like to solve a linear system of the form `A*X=B'`, where `B'` is the transpose of `B`. `A` is a square matrix `N-by-N` and B is `N-by-M`. In lapack/lapacke, the function LAPACKE_dgesv (see an example [here](https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/mkl_sa/11/mkl_lapack_examples/dgesv_ex.c.htm)) is used to solve systems of the form `A*X=B`, where `B` is treated as multiple right-hand side vectors. Is it possible to solve a system of the form `A*X=B'` without having to create a copy of `B` as `Z=B'` by re-ordering its values and then solve `A*X=Z`?

Answer (score 2):

To the very best of my knowledge, LAPACK offers no such functionality. You have to perform the transpose of `B` outside the calls to LAPACK.